# Grunt and hood.ie test database

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, couchdb, jasmine, hoodie

I'm currently running my test suite on [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html), [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html) and [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor). The database library I'm using is [hood.ie](http://hood.ie/), which is a library on top of [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). I start hood.ie using the following code in my Gruntfile:

```
hoodie: {
  start: {
    options: {
      callback: function(config) {
        grunt.config.set('connect.proxies.0.port', config.stack.couch.port);
      }
    }
  }
},
```

However, I would like to have a separate database for running tests, which automatically resets afterwards. This way, the production data won't conflict with the tests.

How should I approach this? I would assume there's some kind of standard way of doing this, as I can imagine other people have come across the same problem, but I'm unable to find anything on the internet.

Comment: How couchdb is configured ?

Comment: CouchDB is configured and run by the hood.ie server, so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this seems to be impossible as the hoodie server does not support it. The best way to go about this is to modify it yourself at [Hood.ie server Github repository](https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-server) by adding a parameter to define the folder in which the data will be stored, which is at the moment hardcoded to 'data' (https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-server/blob/master/lib/core/environment.js#L48)

Something similar to this should work:

```
app_path: path.resolve(project_dir, argv.folder || 'data')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the hoodie task is a 'multitask' you could have a test target in your hood.ie grunt task specific to testing, and then reference this in a grunt command used to run tests e.g:

```
hoodie: {
  start: {
    options: {
      callback: function(config) {
        grunt.config.set('connect.proxies.0.port', config.stack.couch.port);
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      callback: function(config) {
        // Make test specific changes here.
      }
    }
  }
}

// The task that runs tests first starting test deps. 'runtests' can be anything you want.
grunt.registerTask('test', 'Run unit tests', ['hoodie:test', 'runtests']);
```

Note: this will mean any other times you're referencing the hoodie task you'll need to be explicit as otherwise all the specified targets will be run. [See this documentation on multitasks for more info](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks). In this example you'd change hoodie to hoodie:start to run the 'start' task as previously defined.

Comment: This still starts the same instance of the hood.ie server though, so it uses the same data => how can we solve that?

Comment: It seems hoodie start only allows you to change the served location via the --www argument. If you need to change the underlying couch url looks like you might be able to use env vars e.g. COUCH_URL see https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-server/blob/master/lib/core/environment.js#L159